# WordPress: Custom post type and add extra sub page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a little problem that I can't figure out how to solve it. I have an custom post type, and I want to add a extra subpage to that page. For example:

Single post url: `my-post-type/123`
and I want to add an extra like: `my-post-type/123/test` so every post of my postype will have that `/test` also.

where the `/test` is an custom template. I have tried to looking at the `add_rewrite_endpoint` function to se if there is anyway to solve it with that, but with no success.

Code for register post type:

```
function tb_type_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'TBtypes', 'Post Type General Name', 'gct' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'TBtype', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'gct' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'TBtypes', 'gct' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'TBtypes', 'gct' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'gct' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'gct' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'gct' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'gct' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'gct' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'gct' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'gct' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'gct' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'gct' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'gct' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'gct' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'gct' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'gct' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'gct' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'gct' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'gct' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'gct' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'gct' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'gct' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'gct' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'gct' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'gct' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'gct' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                  => 'tbtype',
        'with_front'            => true,
        'pages'                 => true,
        'feeds'                 => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'TBtype', 'gct' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post type for TBTypes', 'gct' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'tb_type_post', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'tb_type_post_type', 0 );
```

All ideas are welcome because i'm really stucked at this problem

Comment: How are you registering your Custom Post Type? What is your custom post type called? Also, what are you trying to solve by doing this? There may be a better way to do what you are doing.

Comment: @disinfor I added it my description now

Comment: Why don't you update your `'slug' => 'tgtype/whatever'` in the $rewrite variable?

Comment: Because if I do that, the the single page will be tbtyp/whateven/123, and I what it do be like tbtype/123/whatever. where whatever is a custom template

Comment: Ah! Right! It's been a long day :) I think I found your answer though: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307713/add-a-permalink-variable-onto-custom-post-type-url-after-post-name-slug